# NETBEANS: how to make jRadioButton non-static so I can add mouseListener to it in PSVM?

Tags: swing, netbeans, jframe, mouseevent, jradiobutton

I only used the drag-and-drop in the JFrame in Netbeans, so I didn't code in hand.

I have a JRadioButton called btnDecafPike and I want that when the user hovers over it, a JFrame appears. This is the code for it and it works:

```
private void btnDecafPikeMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    Coffee_DarkRoast c = new Coffee_DarkRoast();
    c.setVisible(true);
}
```

But when I used this code, the JFrame that appeared wouldn't disappear anymore:

```
private void btnDecafPikeMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    Coffee_DarkRoast c = new Coffee_DarkRoast();
    c.setVisible(true);
}                                         

private void btnDecafPikeMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    Coffee_DarkRoast c = new Coffee_DarkRoast();
    c.setVisible(false);
}
```

So, I try this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

    btnDecafPike.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Beverage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Beverage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Beverage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Beverage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Beverage().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

But it gives me an error and saying "non-static variable btnDecafPike cannot be referenced from a static context" so how do I fix it?

EDIT:

I used this code but it only shows empty tooltip box?

```
private void btnDecafPikeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    btnDecafPike.setToolTipText("Click this button to disable the middle button.");
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `btnDecafPike` has been defined and initialised in some class, maybe you should make you modifications within it.  Why do you want to show a frame when the use mouse overs?  Would a tooltip be more useful?

Comment: Sorry. What is a tooltip?

Comment: A tooltip is a little popup window which popups when the mouse lingers over a control to provide additional context, see [How to use tooltips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used above edited code but only appears upon hover is a small box with no text in

Comment: Don't set the tooltip when the button is clicked, kind of pointless by then, set it when it's initialised, maybe after the `initComponents` method

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to attach the listener from the psvm? Why not in the JFrame()?
\If you still have to do that create a getter on your JFrame which returns the jradiobutton, then add the listener on it. But i wouldn't suggest to do it. 
I assume that you need something like this.

```
  Coffee_DarkRoast c = new Coffee_DarkRoast();
private void btnDecafPikeMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

    c.setVisible(true);
}                                         

private void btnDecafPikeMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    c.setVisible(false);
}
```

Your code is creating a new JFrame to hide, so the old remains on the screen.